# Play sound in jquery mobile on different pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, audio

I need to play sound in background that will repeat all the time - background music. I have added `<audio>` tag in my page html and added event

```
$("#audio-player").on('ended', function() {
  //play again
}
```

in `pageinit` event of the page. And this works, but the music should continue even when I navigate to some other page, and I am not sure how to make this. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: have you added `loop="true"` to `audio` tag?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/g7eeo6y3/

Comment: This worked. I have tried this, and it didn't work on ripple, so I thought I was doing something wrong, but it worked perfectly on device. Please post this as an answer, so I can mark ti. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX to load the new page. Use jQuery's load() to only load the #content part of the new page into the #content div of the current page.

HTML

```
  <header>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
  </header>

  <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>

  <div id="content">
    Page 1 content
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript / jQuery

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('#content').load(target + ' #content');
});
```